# Layout bug on SO user page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Well, I'm slightly lost.  Either someone is tinkering around with the layout or I've done something wrong.  For the past few hours, everything has been fine on Stack Overflow, and then I refresh my user page to see this:

> [image]

Could someone clue me in to what is happening, if something is indeed happening?  The layout is fine on meta.

Comment: There's a chance you inadvertently resized the browser text. Try a Ctrl+0 (or whatever's comparable for your browser)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zooming in/out (by e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Scrollwheel) went mad. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> to reset it. I can reproduce your issue in Chrome if I zoom in a lot and then zoom out until one step before zero.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot.  I did indeed inadvertently zoom in; as it turns out, my mouse has a slight mechanical flaw/software bug that causes it to either scroll up or down one notch every so often.